# Datatables warning in Firebug

Tags: jquery, error-handling, firebug, datatables

So I have a datatable that is being populated by user inputs. When I enter the screen (before I submit anything) I dont throw any warnings in firebug.  After I enter something into the table and submit.  I automatically get returned to the same page, only the table has my submitted information in it.  At this point is when I am getting the error.  Here it is:

```
DataTables warning (table id = 'table'): Unexpected number of TD elements. Expected 5
and got 6. DataTables does not support rowspan / colspan in the table body, and there 
must be one cell for each row/column combination.
```

Seems obvious, but I dont have rowspan or colspan on my table. So I dont know what the problem is.  Also, here is my setup for the datatable:

```
 var table1 = {};
 table1 = O_LANGUAGE = {sEmptyTable: "There is nothing here."};

        $(document).ready(function() {
      var $table= $("#table");
    $table.dataTable({
      "aaSorting": [ [0,'desc'] ], "oLanguage" : bsFaReq.O_LANGUAGE, "bLengthChange": false, "bFilter": false, "bAutoWidth": false, "bInfo": false, "bPaginate": false
      });
```

OKay, so it runs fine, but I cant put it out until I get this warning fixed, any help is appreciated, thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because the there are 5 columns in Your table but data is sent for 6.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to debug the first warning which is "Expected 5 and got 6" which means you are trying to add 6 td's while the rows above were 5 only.